# Can someone explain to me how exactly this is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was looking at a question I recently answered ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641481/why-is-this-syntax-incorrect-in-this-js-snippet#comment45582018_28641481) one if you need it), and it was recently closed by a gold-badge member as a duplicate. I am willing to bet money that it is a duplicate of something, but I can't find it. It was however, closed as a duplicate of a question that asks nothing of the sort of the original question.

Comment: I'm certain something like that's been asked before, but it doesn't read like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @Makoto I know it's been asked before, I can't find the correct duplicate atm, just wondering why it was closed as a duplicate as the one it was.

Comment: I can't tell you *why* they closed it; they may have read it entirely too quickly or something along those lines, or felt that it was similar to the dupe.  Pontificating around the reasons isn't constructive; we're all human and make mistakes.  The key thing here is that now we have a chance to *correct* the mistake.

Comment: By the way - don't edit the question to say "it's not a duplicate".  That's just a reply to the question, which you've done a job of already.

Comment: @Makoto I just thought from reading the help center (again) that you were supposed to edit if you felt it was closed unfairly.

Comment: Right idea, wrong interpretation.  Edit to improve the content of the post, not to make a complaint about how it was closed.

Comment: I should mention that this post is now going through the reopen queue, but I still think it would benefit from an edit that makes it more clear what the question is.

Comment: @KevinBrown I'll make that edit now

Comment: I made an edit further clarifying the edit if anybody would like to visit it.

Comment: Someone who likes that SO question please edit it into shape - right now it looks like "why = is used for assignment and === for comparison" which is really not answerable...

Comment: Well, don't edit.  Once you do, it becomes obvious that the question is incredibly trite and answered with authoritative resources outside of SO.  Whatever value that Q+A has, as little there is, can only be found by the questioner having so little insight in the language he's trying to use that he doesn't even know how to phrase his question properly.  Maybe the next guy will get it wrong the same way.  Whether SO should be a resource for programmers that don't know how to ask a question is, well, another discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

The body of that question *really* looks like it would be a duplicate, but that's mostly due to it not being really clear what is going on. In these cases I would usually recommend **making the original question more clear for future readers** (and **note it in your edit message**), and wait for it to be reopened through the reopen queue.

[What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

> Be sure that you've read the close notice and any comments on the question so you can address any concerns raised there. Addressing the concerns often means **editing the post**, [which any user may do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

*(formatting in original)*

You shouldn't [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7114631) and explain why it's not a duplicate, as that is usually reserved for the OP. It will trigger the post to appear in the reopen queue, and quite often the OP will find their answer from the duplicate.

Comment: Well I wasn't gonna link to the part where he edited it, but geez...at least we're thinking along the same lines.